# After uploading an app to the App Store Sign in with Apple button is not working

Tags: ios, swift, sign-in-with-apple

In my application, there is a sign in with apple feature. Before it was working fine, but after uploading app to the AppStore suddenly it stopped working.

Now I am receiving only,

[core] Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError Code=-7026 "(null)" UserInfo={AKClientBundleID=}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Double check App Capabilities both from Xcode and Apple Developer portal. (I think 7026 indicates a missing Capability)

In general, for this kind of issues, try uploading your app to TestFlight, get it from there, and see if you get the same results, if you do that generally narrows it down to some misconfiguration.